# Ionic3 app not access internet in Samsung phone android 8.0 and above

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, android-9.0-pie

Ionic3 app gets not access the internet in Samsung devices which has android 8.0 & above. In the rest of devices like MI, Oppo, Vivo, Samsung below 8.0 app work perfectly.

I Already add whitelist plugins.

Comment: From Android 9 the request to http is blocked you can read more about https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/08/introducing-android-9-pie.html

Comment: You have to install ssl certificate in your server